# Using private class in Android

Tags: android, class, static, private

Hi I have a question about using private class in Android activities.
Let's say I have a simple listView in an activity.
I want to define an adapter class for this listView(which extends BaseAdapter).
Since the adapter is pretty simple, I want to define a private class in this Activity class.
My question is this.
Is it okay to define this private class non statically? Or is it better practice to define it statically?

If I have to define it statically, I have to pass an object (say List) to this private adapter's constructor then assign this to its member variable in it.
If I define it non statically, I can define List object in Activity class and use it within the private adapter.

Is this okay?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `static variables or classes` makes most times only sence if you want to use the object in another class. 
Since you want to declare your adapter as inner-class inside your activity and declare it `private` it does not make any sense to declare your class as `static`.

If you want to be able to have access to your adapter from an outer-class it might make sense to declare it static, it depends on what you want to do, **but**

> static variables as well as classes should always be declared as
>   public